# Playing sounds on clicking within image - upgrading to html5?

Tags: html, wordpress, onclick, maps, playsound

Sorry - I'm probably too low a level for this site.  My wordpress posts sometimes feature images where clicking in different places plays different sounds. My current method (cannibalized a while back from searches) is shown below.  Now I find they don't play on iPads etc, so I need html5. I have tried to follow various methods online and can't get them to work, or I just don't understand the solution, e.g. this one [Play MP3 with when an image is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955183/play-mp3-with-javascript-html5).  If anyone can help, please be as explicit as possible about where I put various bits of code, whether in posts or in .php files etc. 
If I need more basic tutorials first, perhaps someone could suggest?  Many thanks.

I put this at the top of the post

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
<span id="dummy">
</span>
```

then at the right point inside the post

```
<img src="http://website_path/image.jpg"  width="350" height="312" usemap="#my_image" />
<map name="my_image">
<area shape="rect" coords="20,65,50,95" onclick="playSound('http://website_path/sound.mp3');"  />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this self-answer by ergo:
[innerHTML causes unwanted scroll in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596082/innerhtml-causes-unwanted-scroll-in-chrome)

The first of my bits of code should be replaced with:

```
<audio id="1st_sound">
<source src="1st_sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="1st_sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<audio id="2nd_sound">
<source src=2nd_sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="2nd_sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

etc.

The second bit should be replaced with:

```
<img src="http://website_path/image.jpg" width="350" height="312" usemap="#my_image" /> 
<map name="my_image"> <area shape="rect" coords="20,65,50,95" onClick="document.getElementById('1st_sound').play(); return false;" />
</map>
```

etc.