# HTML5 Audio On Image Click

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, safari

I'm have 2 images on a page which is meant to be opened on a mobile browser such us chrome and safari. When someone clicks on one of the images, they will hear an audio. I have this audio control but I don't know how to incorporate it into images in a way that when someone clicks on an image they will hear an audio.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="cat.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="cat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls>
  <source src="dog.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="dog.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

For example when someone clicks on a cat image, I want them to hear the sound of the cat. I have both versions ogg and mp3. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: That would require he use of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code;

```
<audio id="aud">
    <source src="aud.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="aud.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('aud').play(); return false;">
  Link
</a>
```

But check whole thread here [innerHTML causes unwanted scroll in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596082/innerhtml-causes-unwanted-scroll-in-chrome)